# Fortran pointer dummy argument

Tags: pointers, fortran

I have the following Fortran program. But I don't understand why the output is 4 instead of 1. I am using GNU 6.4 Fortran compiler:

```
program aa

implicit none

real, pointer, dimension(:,:) :: t => null()

integer :: i,j

allocate(t(0:100,20))

do i = 0, 100
  do j = 1, 20 
     t(i,j) = i*j
  end do
end do

call te(t(1:,:))

stop

contains

subroutine te(a)

implicit none

real,dimension(:,:),pointer,intent(in) :: a

print *, a(1,1)

end subroutine te
end program aa
```

Answer (score 2):

The Intel compiler 18.0.2 returns the error message

`/pt.f90(17): error #7121: A ptr dummy may only be argument associated with a ptr, and this array element or section does not inherit the POINTER attr from its parent array.   [T]
call te(t(1:,:))`

Change the line in your subroutine to

`real,dimension(:,:),intent(in) :: a`

and all is good.

Comment: Alternatively, add another pointer declaration in the top-level program and then point that pointer to the array section t(1:,:). Then, pass the array section pointer to the subroutine and all will be fine.

Comment: I submitted https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85868 Let's see how the devs view it. BTW Oracle Studio Fortran `sunf90` returns 1.0.

Comment: Fixed on the trunk of GCC 11. The code is valid Fortran 2008.